# Group two columns, count corresponding values in another column, and put counts in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

I've been out of the database game for a while so I'm a bit rusty, but I was recently presented with the following problem that no one else I know can help me with:

before:

```
nm, lt, size
1, a, sm
1, b, lg
1, a, sm
1, b, lg
2, a, sm
2, a, lg
```

after:

```
num, let, sm, lg
1, a, 2, 0
1, b, 0, 2
2, a, 1, 1
```

I have data resembling the above example. The **size** column can only be one of two values. I need a query to treat the **nm** and **lt** columns as a composite key. That is, each combination should be unique even though they are separate, and a count of the corresponding **size** values should be placed in their respective columns.

The only difference between my example and my actual database is the format of the **nm** and **lt** columns, they contain larger numbers that result in over 5,000 unique combinations, and there are about 1 million rows that need to be tallied up and placed in the **lg** and/or **sm** columns.

I apologize if my explanation is a bit convoluted, hopefully the example will suffice. Any assistance or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quick question - you have duplicate rows here. `1, a, sm` appears twice, and so does `1, b, lg`. This can't happen, because nm and lt are unique as you said. Should those be removed, or is this a typo in your dataset?

Comment: They're not unique in the first table, I need to make them unique in the second table. The first table has about 1 million rows, and I already know that if I make the first two columns unique, it comes down to about 5,000. My problem is getting the third row from the first table, to be counted and placed into the third and fourth rows of the second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  nm,
    lt,
    SUM(case when size = 'sm' then 1 else 0 end) as 'sm',
    SUM(case when size = 'lg' then 1 else 0 end) as 'lg'
from testtable
group by nm,lt;
```

Comment: Here is the sqlfiddle for it - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f39c7/1 - thank you for the answer tick :)